# Vtiger 6 - where are Service Contract tpl files

Tags: php, vtiger

I checked the lang file, found variables, did a search. Nothing.

I want to add custom summary under the detail block, but can't find template files for Service Contracts. There are php Module files, but not tpl files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

my finding is that it uses the shared templates that you can find in `layouts/vlayout/modules/Vtiger/`.

For example, when you click on "Service Contracts" in the menu, you end up in the List View.
That list is managed by `ListViewContents.tpl` in the folder I specified above.

Apparently, you can make a new folder called `ServiceContracts` into `layouts/vlayout/modules/` and copy-paste the file `ListViewContents.tpl` into that directory and Vtiger will use that file to serve the list view for that specific module, and the changes will be picked up automatically.

Comment: You would think it'd work like that, but of course this is just one more inconsistent thing in Vtiger. There are no references to SC's anywhere. I understand what you are saying with the folders and files loading (Ive used this method), but my gripe is that if there are label variables (and there are) then there should be tpl files loading those vars  somewhere. So frustrated with every step I take in this system.